# ¿Por qué mi función no puede retornar void?

Tags: c

Necesito una mano con una sencilla pregunta, tengo el siguiente código:

```
/*
Sumar todos los elementos de un vector ingresado
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 50

void cargar(int v[TAM], int *n);
int sumar(int v[TAM], int n);
int sumar1(int v[TAM], int n, int i, int c);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int vec[TAM];
    int n;

    cargar(vec, &n);

    printf("La suma de los elementos del vector es: %d\n", sumar(vec,n));

    return 0;
}

void cargar(int v[TAM], int *n) {
    int i;
    printf("Ingrese cantidad de elementos que va a contener el vector: "); scanf("%d", &*n);

    for(i= 0; i<*n; i+=1) {
        printf("Ingrese elemento %d: ", i); scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
}

int sumar(int v[TAM], int n) {
    sumar1(v, n, 0, 0);
}

int sumar1(int v[TAM], int n, int i, int c) {    
    if(i<n) return sumar1(v, n, i+1, c+v[i]);
    else return c;
}
```

La pregunta es en sumar, donde le mando como parámetros a `sumar1(v,n,0,0)`, porque tiene que devolver un `int`, y no puede ser `void`. Es lo unico que no entiendo.

Mas claro, es en la función `sumar`, NO en la función `sumar1`.

El programa funciona correcto, solo tengo esa duda, desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: yo no entiendo muy bien su pregunta, y no se si la funcion sumar compilara bien, pero usted pregunta, por que tiene que devolver un int, como le contesto @julianSalas usted lo a definido asi, pero si su pregunta es por que se retorna un int y no void, puede ser porque se diseño para usar el valor de retorno dentro del printf, donde inicialmente se inicia el proceso al llamar a sumar. Saludos

Comment: usando los especificadores de formato puede ver aqui http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/printf_format Saludos

Comment: Creo que te confunde el hecho de que exista un tipo `void *` (puntero a un dato genérico). Dicho a lo bestia `void *`significa: recibo un puntero a un dato genérico y ya me ocupo luego de convertirlo a un tipo concreto usando un cast, un ejemplo típico son las funciones de comparación de `qsort`. Todos los tipos primitivos tienen su correspondiente a puntero `int` --> `int *`, `float` --> `float *` , pero no es el caso de `void`. `void` a secas significa que no devuelve nada en caso de declararlo como retorno de una función: `void fn(int x)`, o que no recibe ningún parámetro `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tiene que retornar `int` por que sino, ¿Cómo recibiría en resultado el `printf`?...

La pregunta aquí es como diablos funciona tu aplicación si `sumar` no esta retornando nada:

```
int sumar(int v[TAM], int n){
    sumar1(v, n, 0, 0);
}
```

Claramente en esta función falta agregar `return`.

```
int sumar(int v[TAM], int n){
    return sumar1(v, n, 0, 0);
}
```

Ahora te preguntaras ¿como funciona correctamente la aplicación entonces?

Sucede que en algunas plataformas y/o algunos compiladores, almacenan el resultado de una función en un registro especifico (siempre el mismo para todas las funciones), por ejemplo el registro `eax` si fuese un X86.

Pero la ultima instruccion de `sumar` fue llamar a `sumar1`, y esta al ejecutar `return` estableció el valor de `eax`. Ahora bien, cuando termina `sumar` (justo después de sumar1) el valor del registro no ha cambiado (ninguna instrucción lo ha cambiado) y así `printf`, que leerá `eax` (pues es la convención) obtiene el resultado correcto.

Pero esto tiene un gran problema, no es portable, quizá funciona en tu plataforma pero hay buenas chances que no funcione si lo compilas en otro tipo de procesadores y/o usando otro compilador.

Según la [norma](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2960.pdf) en § 6.6.3/2 dice (traducción libre)

> Cuando el flujo alcanza el final de una función, es equivalente a no retornar valor (*lease a no establecer el valor que se retorna*). Esto producirá un comportamiento indefinido en una función que retorna valores (*una función no void*)

*nota: lo que esta entre paréntesis lo agregue yo.*

En este caso, lo indefinido te favorece, pero es una practica peligrosa. La forma correcta de escribir ese código es agregando `return` a la función, así todo el comportamiento de la aplicación tiene un comportamiento bien definido.

Comment: Me quedo mucho mas claro, muchas gracias, y si me el return en sumar, gracias a todos! :)

Answer (score 1):

debes fijarte en la declaración del prototipo  de la función.

```
int sumar1(int v[TAM], int n, int i, int c);
```

cuando declaras la función sumar1, le estas diciendo que debe devolver un int, si tu declaras la función como void.

```
void sumar1(int v[TAM], int n, int i, int c);
```

esta no devolverá un valor. De modo que si tu declaras el prototipo como int, el compilador sabrá que retorna esa funcion al momento de ser definida o invocada.